# filtered data disappear after update the value of it in primefaces datatable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I'm trying to edit the retrieved data after filtering, once I cancelled/update the value of the returned value the edited/cancelled row values are disappeared and are not updated, only on the filtered data in the `datatable` in `primefaces 10`

please find my below code and appreciate your kind support :(

```
 <h:form id="table">
                <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center ">
                    <div class="col">

                        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
                        <p:dataTable id="userRecordTable" 
                                     rows="10"
                                     paginator="true"
                                     sortMode="multiple"
                                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                     currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord}-{endRecord} of {totalRecords} records"
                                     rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50,200" 
                                     widgetVar="productTable"
                                     paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                     reflow="true" 
                                     emptyMessage="No items found " filteredValue="#{serviceBean.filterdDataVo}"
                                     var="productVo" value="#{serviceBean.dataVo}" editable="true" 
                                     style="width: 100%">

                            <f:facet name="header">

                                <p:outputPanel class="head-table-serch">

                                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter"  style="width:150px;height: 30px" 
                                                 onkeyup="PF('productTable').filter()" 
                                                 placeholder="Search"
                                                 
                                                 />
                                </p:outputPanel>

                            </f:facet>


                            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{serviceBean.onRowEdit}" update=":table:msgs" />
                            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{serviceBean.onRowCancel}" update=":table:msgs" />
 <p:column headerText="price" filterMatchMode="startsWith" filterBy="#{productVo.price}">


                                <p:cellEditor>
                                    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{productVo.price}" /></f:facet>
                                    <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{productVo.price}" style="width:95%" label="Price"/></f:facet>
                                </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column style="width:35px">
                                <p:rowEditor />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
 </div>

                </div>

            </h:form>
```

Comment: Many dataTable issues in PF10 are fixed already. Can you please try with 11.0.0-RC1?  https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/../migrationguide/11_0_0

Comment: I have tried, same problem! :(

Comment: Might be https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7845